# How to print a user's IP address (if $owner)

Tags: php

I need to print a user's IP address. Here's the code for the moderator panel that comes up when we click on usernames:

```
if($owner == 1 || in_array($userid,$moderatorUserIDs)) {
    $options="<input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[40]."' onClick=javascript:".$caller."kickUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>
    <input type=button value='".$chatrooms_language[41]."' onClick=javascript:".$caller."banUser($uid,0);$close class='invitebutton'>".$options;
}
```

Above the kick/ban button I'd like it to say IP: -ip address-

Again thank you in advance for your help you guys are fantastic.

Sorry for not making it clearer. I don't want to print MY ip address to myself. When I click on their username for the moderator panel comes up, I need it to print THEIR IP address to me.

Thanks for the suggestions so far.

I've entered this into guests.php at the same place where the guests username is assigned and entered into the database:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
                }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }else{
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
    //The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
            $ip = ip2long($ip);
    //The $ip would now look something like: 1073732954
            $sql = "INSERT INTO cometchat_guestip(ip) VALUES('$ip')";
    $dbQuery = mysql_query($sql,$dbLink);
```

Is this correct?

Then on the moderator panel I will call:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'cometchat_guestip' WHERE 1
echo $ip
```

Yes?

Comment: Whose IP? The person who's logged in or the moderator? If the former, you need to be storing that somewhere...

Comment: Yeah the former, the user's IP printed to the moderator.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clients IP address with this:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: Yes but when I click on the moderator panel, wouldn't that just print MY IP address to myself rather than print theirs to me?

Comment: Assign a variable with that for each user and store it in the database. Then, you can retrieve their ip, not yours.

Comment: Ok.. I'll go have a quick google for code to inserting users IP addresses into database then come back to see how to retrieve to print it.